# How to force Windows 10 to use pagefile on usb-connected SSD?

Tags: windows-10, usb, virtual-memory, pagefile

I have a constantly connected USB SSD disk. I'm never going to disconnect it at runtime. It operates in a "better performance mode", not "quick removal". I can configure pagefile on it but after restart the pagefile is not actually created and I see that virtual memory is not increased in Task Manager. What can I do to make Windows actually use it for pagefile?

Comment: USB drives do not get loaded by windows until late in the boot sequence. By the time the USB drive is detected Windows has long since checked whether it has access to the page file, found it missing, and continued without that particular file. Windows only supports truly permanent connected storage devices for page files such as SATA, IDE or NVME drives.

Comment: [ReadyBoost](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/xperf/readyboot-analysis) may be a better solution. Just an FYI,  if running 32GB+ of RAM, there's no purpose in having pagefile enabled on any drive.

Comment: @Mokubai you are the only one person here who explained why it is not possible, I think you should post it as an answer

Comment: @JW0914 what you said is incorrect, I have 32GB of RAM and I have to use a pretty big pagefile to have enough virtual memory or otherwise I encounter out of memory errors even though ram is not fully used.

Comment: "It operates in a «better performance mode»" - that means it's buffering writes in RAM, so it's actually using additional RAM while it's trying to free up more RAM.

Comment: @gronostaj I don't need to free up any physical ram, I need pagefile to get more virtual address space

Comment: @Vlad If you're using a RAM-intensive program, you'll receive that error when the amount of available RAM is not enough to run the program/open the file _(e.g. high-resolution Photoshop files, video editing, gaming, etc.)_, and some programs will set a min. available RAM even though what's being done at that moment may not require that amount. Most users with 32GB+ of RAM will benefit from disabling the pagefile, but a minute percentage may not when using high RAM intensive programs, as RAM will always outperform SSDs.

Comment: @JW0914 disabling pagefile makes it impossible to fully use physical ram because apps always allocate much more than they really need and they fill any amount of ram you have be it 16 or 32 or 64 gb - you will always see out of memory. You can't do anything about it but enable pagefile.

Comment: @vlad That's [factually inaccurate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/introduction-page-file) and the vast majority of users will not have memory issues by disabling the pagefile on systems with 32GB+ of RAM, I have an Alienware 18 with 32GB of RAM, I run multiple VMs in Hyper-V and I disabled my pagefile years ago without issue. There are specific tasks that may require enabling pagefile, but they're limited to high RAM photo and video editing and/or gaming.

Comment: @JW0914 users who don't notice memory issues would never use 32 GB of ram in the first place, I usually have almost 2x more virtual memory allocated than physically used and going without pagefile would waste almost half of my ram.

Comment: RAM is there to be used, not sit dormant. Please read the Microsoft Docs man page I linked to _(please note the first sentence under the [5th section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/introduction-page-file#page-files-in-windows-with-large-physical-memory):"When large physical memory is installed, a page file might not be required to support the system commit charge during peak usage")_, and instead of speaking in hypotheticals, why don't you try disabling the pagefile and see if what you posit comes to pass.

Comment: @JW0914 I tried and it didn't work well. I had out of memory errors despite of having "free" RAM because there was no address space for commit charge available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB disks do not get loaded until late in the boot sequence. Even if the disk is loaded by the UEFI/BIOS then when the OS loads it effectively resets the USB connection during driver initialisation and the disk disappears for at least a short while.

As a result by the time the USB drive is detected Windows has long since checked whether it has access to the page file, found it missing, and continued without it.

Windows only supports truly permanent connected storage devices for page files such as SATA, IDE or NVME drives. Windows knows how to reliably deal with these devices and has been designed around them with native support loaded in the first milliseconds of the OS starting.

USB needs a somewhat different driver stack and isn't handled in the same way as normal disks. At the very least the drive disappearing and reappearing during boot will effectively disable the pagefile.

As a result page files are not supported on USB disks.

Comment: I found out that it's still possible to use a pagefile on a USB disk if I install Windows on that USB disk. It looks like Windows doesn't reset USB connection to a disk where it's installed.

Comment: As far as I know the only way to install to USB is Windows To Go which is an Enterprise feature that is discontinued. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview Any other way is unsupported.

Comment: I installed Windows 10 Pro on USB. I don't say it's supported but it works ok. It didn't want to install there but I found some manual to force installation on USB. May be the correct answer for my question should be: "to put pagefile on USB install Windows on that USB".

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put the Page File on a removable drive.  Windows does not provide that functionality.

Page files are small (in the overall scheme of things) so keep it on drive C:  That is truly the best thing to do.

*"Constantly connected USB Drives"* have a bad habit of getting disconnected also.

[Page File Location](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/how-to-put-page-file-on-external-drive.3621056/)

Read down to Best Solution.

> *"The only way that I have ever seen an external device used for the paging file in Windows 10 is to use a Ready Boost capable device and
> have Superfetch enabled."*
>
> That's not a paging file, it's the app/data cache. Not the same thing.
> You cannot put the paging file on external media. Windows is hardcoded
> to prevent it.